# gradle file build failed

Tags: gradle, build

gradle clean build --stack trace
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\dayasagar.kmr\sun\reliance\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'reliance'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'world-standalone-root'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':reliance-aar:sourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

When I execute the command gradle clean build I get this error

Comment: Share your `build.gradle` file so we can help, but it seems like a classifier issue with your plugin

Answer (score 1):

You get this issue when you are trying to build, a code written with lower version of gradle(<gradle 8), with gradle 8.x. You need to replace "classifier" with "archiveClassifier" in your build.gradle file. For example : classifier = 'abc' to archiveClassifier = 'abc'

Here is the hint in the error you got :
Could not set unknown property '**classifier**' for task ':reliance-aar:sourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.